# Can't listen to print function in __main__.py with unittest.mock

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, sys, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to listen to the `print` function from `__main__.py`. I use the `patch` function from `unittest.mock`.

```
def main_tester(command):
    fake_command()
    capturedoutput = io.StringIO()
    sys.stdout = capturedoutput
    with patch('sys.argv', command.split(" ")):
        from SIESTAstepper import __main__ as rtmain
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return capturedoutput.getvalue()
```

The problem is, it returns an empty string `""` instead of the captured output.

The code is from [here](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/blob/main/tests/testers.py) if you are willing to see the full project.

Comment: There is no `print` statement anywhere in that `__main__.py`.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg But the functions used in `__main__.py` has `print` statements. I can listen elsewhere but not `__main__.py`.

Comment: I don't get it. If there are specific `print` statements that you want to check, why not just mock those directly? That is what the [`assert_called_...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called) methods of the `Mock` class are for. To verify that a mocked object has been called with specific arguments. What is the point of the `StringIO` monkey-patching of the `sys.stdout`?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I am new in unit testing. This is my first time hearing `assert_called_... `. I was patching the  `sys.argv` to be able to use `__main__.py`. Is not it the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Your [`__main__`](https://github.com/eftalgezer/SIESTAstepper/blob/main/SIESTAstepper/__main__.py) module should probably not unconditionally call the `main` function. It is common practice to put that in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. It is one of the [most viewed threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) on this platform.

If you put the `main` call behind that if-statement, you can safely import from your `__main__` module without the import causing the execution of the `main` function.

Then you can properly test `main` because you can import it in your test module and simply call it with whatever arguments you want for testing purposes.

To test specific print statements, you can patch/mock the print function **in the module being tested**. Something like this for example:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

@patch("module_being_tested.print")
def test_some_function_that_should_call_print(mock_print: MagicMock) -> None:
    ...
    some_function(some_argument)
    mock_print.assert_called_once_with(
        "A string it should have been called with"
    )
```

---

In your comment you mentioned you were new to *unit* testing. I just wanted to draw your attention to the definition of unit testing. Because it seems like `main_tester` is supposed to test behavior that is not even part of the `__main__.main` function at all. You should make sure that you actually isolate the units (the functions) you are testing from all your other code. That is where mocking comes in handy.

When you are testing `main`, you should actually **only** test `main` and not other functions being called by `main`.

Comment: How can I return the print output in this function? Or, what should I return to assert?

Comment: I have implemented 
```
@patch("SIESTAstepper.__main__.print")
def main_tester(mock_print: MagicMock, command=None) -> None:
    fake_command()
    from SIESTAstepper.__main__ import main as rtmain
    rtmain(args=command.split(" "))
    mock_print.assert_called_once_with()
```
so far.